# Expresion regular en JavaScript para resolver un problema en un chat

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo el siguiente problema, y es que tengo un chat al cual quiero colocar una expresión regular que sustituya una palabra por el nick del usuario que lo lea. Por ejemplo, yo quiero poner una frase que diga

!!usuario estas leyendo esto

y quiero que en vez de !usuario salga el nick de quien lo está leyendo. Entonces yo extraje el nick del usuario con el cual se va a sustituir el comando correspondiente. Este es el código, es con jQuery:

```
var usuario = $('#log_us').val();
```

el valor que se obtiene es el nick del usuario, entonces yo estuve experimentando:

```
function unescape2(m){
    m=unescape(m);
    m=m.replace(/</g,'&lt;');
    m=m.replace(/>/g,'&gt;');

m=m.replace(/!code(.*)/ig, function(m, gg) {
    if (gg == "" ) return m;
    else return "<div style=\"font-family:monospace; color:#fff; display:inline-block; padding:4px; background-color:#000;\">" + gg + "</div>";
});

m=m.replace(/!anc(.*)/ig, function(m, gg) {
    if (gg == "" ) return m;
    else return "<div class=\"anunciacion oficial\">" + gg + "</div>"
});

m=m.replace(/#meneo(.*)/ig,function(m,gg){
if(gg=='') return m;
return "<div style='display:inline-block;' class='shke'>"+gg+"</div>"
});

m=m.replace(/#uppi(.*)/ig,function(m,gg){
if(gg=='') return m;
return "<div style='-webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg); -moz-transform:rotate(-180deg); -o-transform:rotate(-180deg); transform:rotate(-180deg); display:inline-block;'>"+gg+"</div>"
});

    return m ;
}
```

esa función lo que hace es encerrar varios comandos, por ejemplo el #uppi hace que las letras roten 180 grados, el #meneo que se muevan de lado a lado, y así, entonces no tengo idea como hacer la que quiero ¿Alguien que me guie?

Comment: puedes mejorar tu ejemplo, talvez lo puedas convertir en un ejecutable con el spinner

Comment: @x-rw no no puedo, porque es un chat, requiere de muuucho código como para ponerlo acá-

Comment: tu pregunta es "quiero colocar una expresión regular que sustituya una palabra por el nick del usuario que lo lea" tu pregunta no es todo el chat sino una pequeña funcionalidad que debe tener tu chat

Comment: @x-rw exacto, pero para que la funcionalidad se vea hay que estar conectado al chat. Debe haber una expresión regular que sustituya una palabra por el contenido de una variable, eso es lo único que quiero hacer amigo.

Comment: entonces tu ejemplo no es minimo, te aconsejo que pongas un ejemplo de lo que necesitas

Comment: Creo que deberías reformular tu enunciado a algo como esto: "Tengo una cadena como 'hola hola hola !!usuario hola hola' y tengo que sustituit !!usuario por el valor que hay en una variable javascript. Para ello, he probado lo siguiente (=ejemplo de pruebas=), pero no me funciona porque obtengo este resultado/problema (=problemas encontrados=)"

Answer (score 1):

Prueba añadiendo:

```js
m = 'Saludos !usuario.';
alert('Antes: ' + m);
m = m.replace(/!usuario\b/, $('#log_us').val());
alert('Después: ' + m);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="log_us" value="el_usuario" />
```